# Name 'SettingSerializer' is not defined in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Am trying to expose a nested serializer in my django (rest framework powered) API.

In my `serializers.py` I have:

```
class SettingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Setting
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'platform', 'state') 


class AppSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   settings = SettingSerializer(read_only=True)
   class Meta:
      model = Application
      fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'settings', 'created', 'updated')
```

but when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/applications/`, the url for applications' exposing, Django returns me an error:
`name 'SettingSerializer' is not defined`.

Usually that means that I would have not imported the class into the file I'm working on, but now the `SettingSerializer` is in the same file, so that must be something else.

Can you help me a bit with that, what's wrong now?

Thanks in advance,
Kostas

Comment: Hello, am having the same issue although there is no spelling mistake, import is being done normally as in other serializers etc. Have you found the answer to this issue in the end?